# A-Frame - to many assets?

Tags: assets, aframe

I developed some kind of a Sound-Shooter in A-Frame.
It has actually 7 images and 13 Soundfiles (some between 3-5 MB) in a-asset.
Since november 2019 in my oculus go browser (also Firefox VR) i get the error "Please request the mobile version of this site, to see it in immersive mode". With inspector everything seems fine.
Are there any limitations?!

Addition: Message is from A-Frame. I also got this message on my mobile switching to desktop version of my html-site

Answer (score 1):

Use [A-Frame master](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js) and serve your content over HTTPS

Comment: First thanks. My A-Frame master is from https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.min.js wich seems to be exactly the same. But you are right - content was served over http not s. What is the difference? Anyway - problem is gone. Don't know if A-Frame or Oculus fixed his libraries?!

Comment: Condition http+s is from Version 1.0 of A-Frame. Now you have to use it, otherwise actually Firefox VR throws an errror message. See also a-frame 1.0 docs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is gone without code change on my site (exactly how it came). I don't know if A-Frame or Oculus fixed his libraries.
Message has nothing to do with asset limitations. It's a message from A-Frame concerning rights on the website (DeviceMotion)